# Neural network numerical gradient check not working with matrices using Python-numpy

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matrix, neural-network, gradient

I'm trying to implement a simple numerical gradient check using Python 3 and numpy to be used for neural network.

It works well for simple 1D functions but fails when applied to matrices of parameters.

My guess is that either my cost function is not calculated well for a matrix or that the way I do the numerical gradient check is wrong somehow.

See code below and thanks for your help!

```
import numpy as np
import random
import copy

def gradcheck_naive(f, x):
    """ Gradient check for a function f.

    Arguments:
    f -- a function that takes a single argument (x) and outputs the
         cost (fx) and its gradients grad
    x -- the point (numpy array) to check the gradient at
    """
    rndstate = random.getstate()
    random.setstate(rndstate)
    fx, grad = f(x) # Evaluate function value at original point
    #fx=cost
    #grad=gradient
    h = 1e-4        
    # Iterate over all indexes in x
    it = np.nditer(x, flags=['multi_index'], op_flags=['readwrite'])
    while not it.finished:
        ix = it.multi_index #multi-index number

        random.setstate(rndstate)
        xp = copy.deepcopy(x)
        xp[ix] += h
        fxp, gradp = f(xp) 

        random.setstate(rndstate)
        xn = copy.deepcopy(x)
        xn[ix] -= h
        fxn, gradn = f(xn) 
        numgrad = (fxp-fxn) / (2*h)

        # Compare gradients
        reldiff = abs(numgrad - grad[ix]) / max(1, abs(numgrad), abs(grad[ix]))
        if reldiff > 1e-5:
            print ("Gradient check failed.")
            print ("First gradient error found at index %s" % str(ix))
            print ("Your gradient: %f \t Numerical gradient: %f" % (
                grad[ix], numgrad))
            return

        it.iternext() # Step to next dimension

    print ("Gradient check passed!")

#sanity check with 1D function
exp_f = lambda x: (np.sum(np.exp(x)), np.exp(x))
gradcheck_naive(exp_f, np.random.randn(4,5)) #this works fine

#sanity check with matrices
#forward pass
W = np.random.randn(5,10)
x = np.random.randn(10,3)
D = W.dot(x)

#backpropagation pass
gradx = W

func_f = lambda x: (np.sum(W.dot(x)), gradx)
gradcheck_naive(func_f, np.random.randn(10,3)) #this does not work (grad check fails)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! (my math teacher would be so proud...)

The short answer is that I was mixing up matrices dot product and element wise product.

When using an element wise product, the gradient is equal to:

```
W = np.array([[2,4],[3,5],[3,1]])
x = np.array([[1,7],[5,-1],[4,7]])
D = W*x    #element-wise multiplication

gradx = W

func_f = lambda x: (np.sum(W*x), gradx)
gradcheck_naive(func_f, np.random.randn(3,2))
```

When using the dot product, the gradient becomes:

```
W = np.array([[2,4],[3,5]]))
x = np.array([[1,7],[5,-1],[5,1]])
D = x.dot(W)

unitary = np.array([[1,1],[1,1],[1,1]])
gradx = unitary.dot(np.transpose(W))

func_f = lambda x: (np.sum(x.dot(W)), gradx)
gradcheck_naive(func_f, np.random.randn(3,2))
```

I was also wondering how did the element wise product behave with matrices of not equal dimensions like below:

```
x = np.random.randn(10)
W = np.random.randn(3,10)

D1 = x*W
D2 = W*x
```

Turns out that D1=D2 (same dimension as W=3x10) and my understanding is that x is being broadcasted by numpy to be a 3x10 matrix to allow the element wise multiplication.

Conclusion: when in doubt, write it out with small matrices to figure out where the error is.